# Who coined the name "cosmological constant"?

Tags: cosmology, terminology

I am aware that Albert Einstein first added the $\Lambda$-term to his field equations in his 1917 paper "Cosmological considerations in the general theory of relativity" (german: "Kosmologische Betrachtungen zur allgemeinen Relativitätstheory").

However, his orginial label for the constant was a "vorläufig unbekannte universelle Konstante $\lambda$", which translates to "for the moment unknown universal constant $\lambda$". I am interested in who first spoke of "cosmological constant", i.e. who coined the name that is most common for this constant nowadays and in what paper/publication was it first named as such.

Comment: In this book, The Universe of General Relativity editor: A.J. Kox, Jean Eisenstaedt https://l24.im/gNsEed they cite de Sitter, who says, Einstein himself named this constant as "Cosmological Constant." p.162 This may have some authority since they wrote a book together.

Comment: Where does Einstein use "vorläufig unbekannte universelle Konstante " ?

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you very much, this helps me a lot!
Concerning his use of "vorläufig unbekannte universelle Konstant: In [Einstein, A. (1917). "Kosmologische Betrachtungen zur allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie". Sitzungsberichte der Königlich Preußischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin] he states it on page 151, line 6-9. It his however not a "name" per se but rather a describtion. In the english version of this article - see [here](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/442) - the same passage can be found on page 430 in the passage before equation (13a),